# Remove subarrays having duplicate value at the same index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, duplicates

I have a multi-dimensional array that contains a lot of information about various objects.  I'm looking to remove all but the first instance of arrays that contain similar information:

```
multi_array = [
  ["Nissan", "Altima", "tan", "2016", "80000"], 
  ["Ford", "F-150", "silver", "2012", "120000"], 
  ["Nissan", "Altima", "red", "2009", "50000"], 
  ["Audi", "A4", "blue", "2014", "30000"]
]
```

In the above example I want to remove any of the subarrays that have the instance of "Altima" in it so that result would be:

```
fixed_multi_array = [
  ["Nissan", "Altima", "tan", "2016", "80000"], 
  ["Ford", "F-150", "silver", "2012", "120000"], 
  ["Audi", "A4", "blue", "2014", "30000"]
]
```

What's the fastest way to do this in ruby (or Ruby on Rails)?

#### Update:

*Should have clarified, I'm looking to de-duplicate based on a value that's always in the same position of the sub-arrays.  So, in example above I'm always looking to de-dupe only on value in position 1 of the sub-arrays.*

Comment: What constitutes "similar" information? For example, since `array_a` has "80000", can no other sub-array contain that value? Does this go for any value that has been in a previous sub-array?

Comment: Sorry, it's similar information that will always be in the same position of the sub-array.  So, I'm looking to de-duplicate just off of position 2 of the sub-arrays

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
fixed_multi_array = multi_array.uniq{|x| x[1]}
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/CWVP)

Comment: Since it's Rails you can do a point free version: `multi_array.uniq(&:second)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
multi_array.group_by {|i| i[1]}.values.map(&:first)
```